# Read a message from Listener using org.springframework.jms.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jms, spring-jms

I am working on Standalone Application with Spring Configuration. I have to read the message from the Queue. So for that i am using org.springframework.jms.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer in Spring ApplicationContext.xml. My ApplicationContext.xml file contains.

```
<!-- Config property -->
<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>file:resources/config.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
    <property name="order" value="0" />
</bean>

<!-- App config properties -->

<bean id="configProperties" class="aero.sita.uatp.server.utilities.ConfigProperties">
    <property name="properties">
        <props>
                    <prop key="prefix.correlation">${prefix.correlation}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>


<!-- jndi Template -->
<bean id="jndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
    <property name="environment">
        <props>
            <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">${broker.initialContexFactory}</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">${broker.provide.url}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- JMS Connection factory -->
<bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiTemplate">
        <ref bean="jndiTemplate" />
    </property>
    <property name="jndiName">
        <value>${broker.connectionFactory}</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Auth (Payment) Request queue -->
<bean id="paymentRequestQueue" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiTemplate">
        <ref bean="jndiTemplate" />
    </property>
    <property name="jndiName">
        <value>${payment.request}</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Auth (Payment) Response queue -->
<bean id="paymentResponseQueue" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiTemplate">
        <ref bean="jndiTemplate" />
    </property>
    <property name="jndiName">
        <value>${payment.response}</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- JMS Template -->
<bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
    <property name="explicitQosEnabled" value="true" />
    <property name="timeToLive" value="${payment.request.expiration}" />
    <property name="receiveTimeout" value="${payment.response.receive.timeout}" />
</bean>

<bean id="messageSender" class="aero.sita.uatp.server.MessageSender">
    <property name="jmsTemplate" ref="jmsTemplate" />
    <property name="queue" ref="paymentResponseQueue" />
    <property name="configProperties" ref="configProperties" />
</bean>

<bean id="authorisationServiceImpl" class="aero.sita.uatp.server.AuthorisationServiceImpl">
    <property name="messageSender" ref="messageSender" />
    <property name="configProperties" ref="configProperties" />
</bean>


<bean id="authorisationResponseHandler" class="aero.sita.uatp.server.AuthorisationResponseHandler">
    <property name="configProperties" ref="configProperties" />
    <property name="messageSender" ref="messageSender" />
</bean>



<!-- and this is the message listener container -->

<bean id="jmsContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="autoStartup" value="TRUE" />
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
    <property name="destination" ref="paymentRequestQueue" />
    <property name="messageListener" ref="authorisationResponseHandler" />

</bean>
```

And my Main Class to load the ApplicationContext XML.

```
public class MainTestClient {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Starting Client Application");
    AbstractApplicationContext context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("resources/applicationContext.xml");
    System.out.println("Spring context loaded.");
    context.registerShutdownHook();
    System.out.println("ShutdownHook registered.");

}
```

Below is the class for listener AuthorisationResponseHandler Class which listens to the Queue.

```
public class AuthorisationResponseHandler implements MessageListener {

private ConfigProperties configProperties;

/**
 * Gets triggered when a message is arrived at the queue. It adds the
 * response received to a concurrent hash map
 * @param message
 */
public void onMessage(Message message) {
    try {
        System.out.println("First Node received message with JMSCorrelationID:"
                + message.getJMSCorrelationID());


    } catch (JMSException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here is my question. When i start the application, my listener class is not waiting for the message to acquire. Rather the class initializes and closes with out listening to the queue.

Command to start the class

```
/app/sw/oracle/mw/sunjdk-7-x64/bin/java -cp /app/dev-data/node1/support/tactical_tools/gwatest/server/GWAServerTest.jar aero.sita.uatp.server.MainTestClient
```

The output which i am receiving.

```
   Starting Client Application
Nov 23, 2015 7:13:08 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext@610d3d99: startup date [Mon Nov 23 07:13:08 UTC 2015]; root of context hierarchy
Nov 23, 2015 7:13:08 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from file [/app/dev-data/node1/support/tactical_tools/gwatest/server/resources/applicationContext.xml]
Nov 23, 2015 7:13:08 AM org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport loadProperties
INFO: Loading properties file from URL [file:resources/config.properties]
Nov 23, 2015 7:13:08 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1c9e8392: defining beans [propertyConfigurer,configProperties,jndiTemplate,connectionFactory,paymentRequestQueue,paymentResponseQueue,jmsTemplate,messageSender,authorisationServiceImpl,authorisationResponseHandler,jmsContainer]; root of factory hierarchy
Nov 23, 2015 7:13:10 AM org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup start
INFO: Starting beans in phase 2147483647
Spring context loaded.
ShutdownHook registered.
Nov 23, 2015 7:13:10 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext doClose
INFO: Closing org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext@610d3d99: startup date [Mon Nov 23 07:13:08 UTC 2015]; root of context hierarchy
[alaric@lautpyy003d ~/support/tactical_tools/gwatest/server]$
```

Here i could see that the Spring Context is loaded properly but the console is not waiting for the onMessage method that was written in AuthorisationResponseHandler Class. I am expecting the console to wait for the Message to come in and print the message after it comes in. Am i missing anything in initializing the Listener?

The above question is answered. But now i am facing a new Issue. I am calling the sendMessage function from Main method and it gives Null Pointer Exception.

Main method:

```
public void start()
    {
        AuthorisationServiceImpl authorisationServiceImpl = new AuthorisationServiceImpl();
        try {
            authorisationServiceImpl.fromMain();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Starting Client Application");
        AbstractApplicationContext context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("resources/applicationContext.xml");
        System.out.println("Spring context loaded.");
        context.registerShutdownHook();
        System.out.println("ShutdownHook registered.");

        MainTestClient mainTestClient = new MainTestClient();
        mainTestClient.start();



    }
```

And the method that i am calling in another class is

```
package aero.sita.uatp.client;

import javax.jms.BytesMessage;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.Queue;
import javax.jms.Session;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;
import org.springframework.jms.core.MessageCreator;

import aero.sita.uatp.client.utilities.ConfigProperties;

/**
 * AuthorisationServiceImpl
 * @author Sunil.Gogula
 */

public class AuthorisationServiceImpl {

    @Autowired
    private MessageSender messageSender;


    private MessageReceiver messageReceiver;

    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;
    private Queue queue;


    public JmsTemplate getJmsTemplate() {
        return jmsTemplate;
    }



    public void setJmsTemplate(JmsTemplate jmsTemplate) {
        this.jmsTemplate = jmsTemplate;
    }



    public Queue getQueue() {
        return queue;
    }



    public void setQueue(Queue queue) {
        this.queue = queue;
    }



    public MessageReceiver getMessageReceiver() {
        return messageReceiver;
    }



    public void setMessageReceiver(MessageReceiver messageReceiver) {
        this.messageReceiver = messageReceiver;
    }

    private ConfigProperties configProperties;


    public void fromMain() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Init method called");
        String message = "AAA-MM-CCC";
        long count = new Long("000001").longValue();
        while (true)
        {
            //container.start();
            StringBuffer corelationId = new StringBuffer();

            if (count == 1000000) {
                count = new Long("000001").longValue();
            }

            corelationId.append(message);
            corelationId.append(String.format("%6s", String.valueOf(count)).replace(' ', '0'));
            byte[] myvar = "Message".getBytes();
            System.out.println("Writing message having correlationId: " + corelationId.toString() + " to the queue.");
            sendMessage(corelationId.toString(),myvar);
            count++;
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }


    }



    /*public boolean sendMessage(String correlationId) throws ServiceException {
        byte[] myvar = "Message".getBytes();
        boolean response = false;
        try {
            MessageSender messageSenderVar = new MessageSender();
            System.out.println("Writing message having correlationId: " + correlationId + " to the queue.");
            // writing message to the request queue. 
            sendMessage(correlationId,myvar);
            //messageReceiver.getMessage();

        }catch(Exception e) {

            throw new ServiceException("Exception:",e);
        }
        return response;
    }
    */
    public void sendMessage(final String correlationId, final byte[] bytes) {
        this.jmsTemplate.send(this.queue, new MessageCreator() {
            public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
                BytesMessage bytesMessage = session.createBytesMessage();
                bytesMessage.setJMSCorrelationID(configProperties.getPREFIX_VALUE() + correlationId);

                // message will follow expiration time as configured in properties
                bytesMessage.writeBytes(bytes);
                return bytesMessage;
            }
        });
        System.out.println("Message " + configProperties.getPREFIX_VALUE() + correlationId + " with correlation id: " + configProperties.getPREFIX_VALUE() + correlationId + " written to the queue.");
    }



    public MessageSender getMessageSender() {
        return messageSender;
    }

    public void setMessageSender(MessageSender messageSender) {
        this.messageSender = messageSender;
    }



    public ConfigProperties getConfigProperties() {
        return configProperties;
    }

    public void setConfigProperties(ConfigProperties configProperties) {
        this.configProperties = configProperties;
    }

}
```

I am getting Null Pointer Exception while calling sendMessage Method. Is there any problem in calling the non static methods from Static Method?

```
Starting Client Application
Nov 23, 2015 12:49:53 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext@5ba28182: startup date [Mon Nov 23 12:49:53 UTC 2015]; root of context hierarchy
Nov 23, 2015 12:49:53 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from file [/app/dev-data/node1/support/tactical_tools/gwatest/client1/resources/applicationContext.xml]
Nov 23, 2015 12:49:54 PM org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport loadProperties
INFO: Loading properties file from URL [file:resources/config.properties]
Nov 23, 2015 12:49:54 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@6b915330: defining beans [propertyConfigurer,configProperties,jndiTemplate,connectionFactory,paymentRequestQueue,paymentResponseQueue,jmsTemplate,messageSender,authorisationResponseHandler,authorisationServiceImpl,jmsContainer]; root of factory hierarchy
Nov 23, 2015 12:49:55 PM org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup start
INFO: Starting beans in phase 2147483647
Spring context loaded.
ShutdownHook registered.
Init method called
Writing message having correlationId: AAA-MM-CCC000001 to the queue.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at aero.sita.uatp.client.AuthorisationServiceImpl.sendMessage(AuthorisationServiceImpl.java:114)
        at aero.sita.uatp.client.AuthorisationServiceImpl.fromMain(AuthorisationServiceImpl.java:86)
        at aero.sita.uatp.client.MainTestClient.start(MainTestClient.java:15)
        at aero.sita.uatp.client.MainTestClient.main(MainTestClient.java:31)
```

When i call the sendMessage Normally without Main Method then i am able to connect successfully.

Comment: Your just running a main class directly so it will come to an end once instructions set is complete. What is your expectation to continuously run or take only one message from queue?

Comment: Run continuously until i manually stop the program.

Comment: meaning, that i need to start continuously read messages from queue until i interrupt (ctrl+C). And the program should keep on listening to that queue

Comment: Then create a thread from main method then add a infinite loop to it. There are various ways to create a thread, i would recommend to use concurrency package to create it.

Comment: Instead of the `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` use the `DefaultMessageListenerContainer`.

Comment: Thanks HumanAlgorithm That idea worked. Thanks Very Much

Comment: Hi Deinum, I have to use messageSelector property and that is available in SimpleMessageListenerContainer.